# How to get HTML tags data for any website currently open in webview in android studio

Tags: android, html, webview

[image]I am new in android. I need some serious help in android studio. Suppose I have a website url http://www.exampledomain.com that is currently open in webview in my application in android studio. I want to get the html data of that webpage in the form of string in android studio after clicking a button. How can I get html of the webview page in easy method in android. Thankyou so much in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Async task and download the html data of the website http://www.exampledomain.com

HttpManager.class

```
public class HttpManager {

public static String getData(String uri) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringbuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        return stringbuilder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(reader != null){
            try{
                reader.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

AsyncTask code:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //the variable result will contain all the contents you need.
}
```

}

Calling Async task from mainactivity:

```
 MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
 myTask.execute("http://www.exampledomain.com");
```

If the above is not your requirement, try the following code

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context myApp = this;

@JavascriptInterface
public void processHTML(String html) {
    if (html == null)
       return;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  browser.addJavascriptInterface(this, "HTMLOUT");
  browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
      }
  });
  browser.loadUrl("http://www.exampledomain.com");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your generous response... But I have this code and used already to get html tags. But now I want to get the website html tag of the currently website open in the webview control in android studio... Generous help will be highly appreciated in this regard... 
Best Regards

Comment: i have added another method to view the source code of the website. i hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your generous response again. I added one picture with the above question. What I want now is illustrated in the picture with example. Please read it and help me out. I am waiting for your response...
Best Regards